# UnsatisfiableError - how to understand this error

Tags: python, airflow, conda

I'm trying to install airflow in a conda environment (python 3.9) and get the following:

`conda install --name my_env -c conda-forge airflow`:

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
> to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:
>
> Specifications:
>
> - airflow -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
>
> Your python: python=3.9

My main question here:
**how do I read the specification line? for example, the `3.9.0a0` bit makes me feel like it should comply with python 3.9, but clearly, it doesn't**

And then a couple of sidenotes:

1. where in the [conda-forge package](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/airflow) do I see this specification? If it wasn't a direct conflict with `python`, I'd guess it's some transitive dependency conflict, but this feels like something that should be explicitly stated.
2. if anyone sees a simple solution to installing airflow in a conda + python 3.9 environment please let me know (although this is not what this question is about)

Comment: On the sidenotes: 1) dependencies can be viewed with `conda search conda-forge::airflow=2.1` (version included so it doesn't show every build ever), or on Anaconda Cloud, go to **Files** tab and click the "(i)" icon. 2) there [is no Python 3.9 build upstream](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation.html#prerequisites), so until that's there it's very unlikely a Conda Forge maintainer with push ahead on building one.

Comment: @merv, the `conda search conda-forge::airflow=2.1` doesn't actually show the dependencies, it just shows me `version`, `build`, and `channel`

Comment: Oops sorry - I forgot the `--info` flag! Should be `conda search --info conda-forge::airflow=2.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|` is saying: "greater than or equal to 3.8 and less than 3.9". Then it's followed by another pipe representing another `or`, saying greater than or equal to 3.7, but less than 3.8, etc. All the pipes `|` are `or` signs. Downgrade to 3.8 and you should be able to run it.

It would be more intuitive if it said: `2.7 or 3.5 - 3.8`, which is what it says but more verbosely.